# Stata plot in R/Python

Tags: python, r, statistics, stata

Which function was used for the following plot in R?
At least it looks like a predefined function to me.

Edit: Okay it seems to be Stata according Claudio.

New question:
Is there anything comparable in python/R to get this output?
How to calculate Coef.? What kind of coefficient is this?

[image]

Comment: None: that's a Stata standard output, not R. Or your question is "how to get similar output in R"?

Comment: Ah okay. I did not know that it is Stata. 
Is there a similar output in R/Python possible?

Comment: Looks like Stata.

Comment: If you build a regression model in R, and then use ```summary(model_name)``` you'll have most of the outputs as shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pystata` package which allows you to run stata in a Python environment. You can download it from [here](https://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/pystata/)

Comment: It is not coefplot. It's just a simple linear regression, run with the `regress` command

Comment: @C.Robin thanks for the comment. I edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

We could get the same information with `lm()` in R and get the tables in combination with `broom` and `kable`:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ disp + qsec, data=mtcars)
summary(model) # show results

coefficients(model) # model coefficients
confint(model, level=0.95) # CIs for model parameters
fitted(model) # predicted values
residuals(model) # residuals
anova(model) # anova table
vcov(model) # covariance matrix for model parameters
influence(model) # regression diagnostics


Combining with:
library(broom) # for tidy()
library(knitr) # for kable()

out <- tidy(model)
out1 <- tidy(anova(model))
kable(out1)
kable(out)
```

output:

```
|term      | df|     sumsq|    meansq|  statistic|   p.value|
|:---------|--:|---------:|---------:|----------:|---------:|
|disp      |  1| 808.88850| 808.88850| 74.8166388| 0.0000000|
|qsec      |  1|   3.62193|   3.62193|  0.3350037| 0.5671961|
|Residuals | 29| 313.53676|  10.81161|         NA|        NA|
> kable(out)


|term        |   estimate| std.error|  statistic|   p.value|
|:-----------|----------:|---------:|----------:|---------:|
|(Intercept) | 25.5045079| 7.1840940|  3.5501356| 0.0013359|
|disp        | -0.0398877| 0.0052882| -7.5428272| 0.0000000|
|qsec        |  0.2122880| 0.3667758|  0.5787951| 0.5671961|
```